# Register multiple interceptors in castle windsor fluent

Tags: castle-windsor, aop, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

How do I register multiple interceptors using the fluent API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a component?

`Component.For<Foo>().Interceptors<TestInterceptor1, TestInterceptor2>();`